# How do I remove parts of a sentence?

Tags: php

You are with Andy. Good job!

```
Hello! You are with Naruto-san. Good job!
Hello! You are with DragonFangîŠ. Good job!
Hello! You are with Adam Chan. Good job!
Hello! You are with Dudeî„­. Good job!
Hello! You are with Signore. Good job!
Hello! You are with Athena. Good job!
Hello! You are with EL NwithJAîŒ‘. Good job!
Hello! You are with Keeperî„­â„¢. Good job!
```

Using PHP, how can I strip "Hello! You are with " and ". Good job!"? so I can store the name into a variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$line="Hello! You are with Andy. Good job!";
$bad=array("Hello! You are with ",". Good job!");
$name = str_replace($bad,"",$line);
echo $name;
```

Comment: This is hot. I like how neat it is and efficient it is.

Answer (score 4):

You could try some regular expressions:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/Hello! You are with (.*?)\. Good job!/",$input,$matches);
$name = $matches[1];
```

Comment: @stereofrog It's slower than `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like the only thing that changes in your sentences is the name, you could use `str_ireplace` like this:

```
$sentence = "Hello! You are with Andy. Good job!";
$name = str_ireplace(array('Hello! You are with ', '. Good job!'), array('',''), $sentence);
```